# Can i send sms with image(MMS) automatically in flutter

Tags: sms

i know how to send  automatically,
but i can't send message automatically with image.
help me.
how to send message with image.

Sending MMS with Flutter
I'm looking for a way to programmatically send text + image in SMS message using Flutter (so basically an MMS). Hope anyone could help me out here.( automatically)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there’s no easy way right now. It’s very frustrating. I want this as well for my app. The only way to do it right now is to write your own way of doing it from scratch. The contactsservice library does not have this feature and likely won’t for a long time (they don’t seem to work on it very much).